# How can I access the "Permission denied" file /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/direction from a user space program

Tags: c, linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, sysfs

```
int fd;
ssize_t w;
char i[35]="/sys/class/gpio/gpio";

strcat(i,a);

strcat(i,"/direction");

fd=open(i,O_WRONLY);
if(fd==-1){
    perror("direction:");
    return(-3);
```

It is the part of my code. I am writing a program for GPIO of Raspberry Pi using sysfs file access. I want to access this path by the above code but it was not opened and the error shown was Permission denied. How can I can access this file?

Comment: Did you try using `sudo`... Otherwise change permission of sys to your current user.

Comment: I am a student and in learning process.Could you please elaborate how to change permission of sys, and how to implement sudo command in my C program

Comment: It is a very broad matter. You should  take a look [here for sudo command](https://www.linux.com/blog/how-use-sudo-and-su-commands-linux-introduction) or [here for permission](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php) Both case you have to have a sudoer user or a superuser..

Comment: Given links tell something sudo command and about permission. I want a C program that can replace or amend above the code

Comment: Permission are managed my OS. You can't do that without permissions.  It's a dog chasing its own tail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not logged-in as the pi user (the default one), add your user to the "gpio" group. That would give you read/write/execute permissions to the GPIO files.

Comment: How would i add my user to the "gpio" group, and how would i check that I am the default user or the other one??

Comment: Do you see a pi@raspberrypi in your terminal prompt?

Comment: And in order to see your user groups, you open a terminal and type      groups yourusername. For example if I type groups pi, I get the following groups; pi : pi adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev spi i2c gpio debian-transmission. As you can see pi is by default in the gpio group. For adding an existing user to an existing group, see the following [link]http://www.howtogeek.com/50787/add-a-user-to-a-group-or-second-group-on-linux/[/link]

Comment: Sorry, I am new to SE answering, so remove the square bracket in the end from the link above in order to not get a 404

Comment: By the way I logged-in as the pi user

Comment: do a groups pi and see if you are member of the gpio group

Comment: Apart from that, do an ls -l /sys/class/gpio/ and see the permissions and if there is your wanted gpio.

Comment: Kindly resolve the issue, i am already the default user or pi user and. Why is /sys/class/gpio/gpio2/direction file not opening from above process?  What is the problem in above code

Comment: I have tested the code from the wiki and it works for me. Note that you need to write to the export file your wanted pin and then to the unexport when finished